# Making Ubuntu Download Bootable from USB

Tags: boot, usb

How can I make the Ubuntu download bootable from a USB stick without downloading third party software?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the host OS from where you want to create the bootable USB?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're on Linux,

- Open a terminal and type `sudo su`
- `lsblk` to note which device is your USB.
- `mkdir /mnt/myusb && mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/myusb` (replace **b1** with your actual usb device id, /dev/sdb1 in my case)
- `grub-install --force --no-floppy --boot-directory=/mnt/myusb/boot /dev/sdb` (replacing **b** if necessary)
- `cd /mnt/myusb/boot/grub`
- `wget pendrivelinux.com/downloads/multibootlinux/grub.cfg`
- Copy the iso to the root of your pen drive and modify the **grub.cfg** file in order to load the isos from the correct location.

  ```
  set timeout=10
  set default=0
  menuentry "Run Ubuntu Live ISO" {
  loopback loop /ubuntu-xx-xx-i386.iso linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-xx-xx-i386.iso splash --
  initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
  }
  ```

(replace "/ubuntu-**xx-xx-i386**.iso" with the correct file name)

- Open any disk utility software and make sure that the partition has got the "boot" flag. If not, set it.

**DONE!**

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal window and enter this command

`sudo apt-get install unetbootin`

to install Unetbootin from the Ubuntu repositories.

Once added to your system, plug in the flashdrive, launch unetbootin, select the version of *buntu you have already downloaded, and unetbootin will create a bootable LiveUSB drive.